# Как передать данные между экранами в Чистой архитектуре?

Tags: android, архитектура

Исходные классы: 
`EventListPresenter` и `EventFiltersPresenter` - презентеры, `EventRepository` - репозиторий,
`EventFilters` - java класс, который содержит поля фильтров.

Задача:

`EventListPresenter` должен уметь отображать `Event` по фильтрам. Пользователь настраивает фильтры на отдельном экране. После настройки фильтров нажимает кнопку "Применить" и переходит обратно на экран со списком, но уже должны примениться новые фильтры. Как это правильно сделать в Чистой архитектуре?

Слышал, что делать это через `ActivityOnResult`  - плохая практика, можете объяснить почему и как правильно, если можно с примером (псевдокод)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Чистая архитектура** говорит только о зависимостях между слоями приложения (бизнес логика ничего не знает о внешнем представлении и так далее). Понятие "экранов" в приложении относится к презентейшн слою, который можно реализовать различными MV* паттернами. Например MVP.

Самое удобное и правильное для передачи событий между экранами (то есть между их презентерами) - создать общую модельку `CurrentFilter` с текущим фильтром в памяти.

Тогда `EventListPresenter` подпишется на обновления этой модельки и будет реагировать на изменения фильтра, то есть запрашивать новые данные из репозитория.

А `EventFiltersPresenter` будет менять фильтр внутри этой модельки.

Есть множество способов это реализовать, но наиболее распространенным является использование `CustomScoup` Dagger 2. То есть первый презентер `EventListPresenter` при инициализации создаст `CurrentFilter`, а при уничтожении очистит. Так как второй экран запускается заведомо после `EventListPresenter`, то для него `CurrentFilter` уже будет доступен.

Использование `onActivityResult` допустимо для запуска внешних приложений типа камеры, тогда результат полученный в `Intent` передается презентеру и дальше уже обрабатывается там. 
В других случаях это менее удобно, так как передавать можно только серелизуемые данные и в ответственность Активити попадает еще и логика передачи данных кроме отображения.

Comment: `Так как второй экран запускается заведомо после EventListPresenter, то для него CurrentFilter уже будет доступен.`


А что если на втором экране пользователь свернет приложение и система его убьет? 
и `CurrentFilter` не будет инициализирован первым презентором

Comment: Если экраны у вас сделаны на основе фрагментов, то фрагмент менеджер их восстановит, и необходимые скоупы тоже будут созданы.

Answer (score 8):

Если вы хотите следовать принципам "чистой архитектуры", под которой имеется ввиду строгое распределение на слои, каждый из которых отвечает только за свой конкретный отрезок работы (`Single Responsibility`), то использовае`onActivityResult` нарушает как раз нарушает принцип единой ответственности слоя.

Рассмотрим распостраненный вариант архитектуры:

```
View -> Presenter -> Repository -> Model
```

Каждый знает только о следующем и/или предыдущем слое. То есть `Model` ничего не знает о `Presenter` и `View`. На всякий случай уточню, что `View`  это зачастую `Activity` или `Fragment`. И тут непресредственно ответ на Ваш последний вопрос: `onActivityResult` вернет Вашу модель во `View` (который ответственный за вызов новых экранов), то есть в слой, который как бы за модель не ответственный.

Если придерживаться такой архитектуре, то используется `interactor`. Обычно он представляет собой интерфейс, с одним методом `interaction()`, который выполняет задачу и передает данные/модели средствами `Event bus`, который "слушает" нужные события в нужных местах.

Своим ответом я не заявляю о правильности использования только такого подхода. Такие вопросы всегда являются повод демагогий и бесконечных обсуждений, но в итоге все соглашаются, что  к правильной (значит гибкой, расширяемой и взаимозаменяемой) архитектуре надо стремиться, но единственного правильного варианта нет, а каждый выбирает что ему удобнее. Рекомендую ознакомиться с [архитектурным гайдом от гугла](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/index.html), который был представлен на Google I/O 2017.