# Где хранить временные данные, нужные отображению, в MVP?

Tags: android, архитектура

Есть поля даты во вью, значение в которые я устанавливаю через `DatePickerDialog` а результат выбранной даты отображаю в тектовом поле в виде строки. Причем при последующем показе `DatePickerDialog` мне надо его проинициализировать предыдущей выбранной датой.

То есть мне нужно где-то хранить сырое значение `Date`
Где его хранить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если диалог показывается как часть реализации `View`, то есть у него нет своего презентера, то нормально будет сырую дату хранить в теге того поля по клику которого открывается диалог с выбором даты. Можно сказать это внутрення кухня реализации `View`.

Если диалог открывать как отдельный экран и привязать к нему свой презентер, то возвращать данные надо как обмен данными между презентерами. Ответ на этот кейс описан здесь: [Как передать данные между экранами в Чистой архитектуре?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/676423/253569)

Answer (score 0):

`Date` выбранная в диалоге обычно *нужна для дальнейшей работы*, верно? То есть мы эту дату не просто так выбрали в диалоге и отображаем в поле.
А все нужные данные должны идти через `Presenter`, чтобы он мог их использовать.

То есть выбрав дату в `DatePickerDialog` мы передаем её в `Presenter`, а презентер уже говорит *View* где и как нужно отобразить эту дату (в нашем случае в поле, в виде строки).

Поэтому **лучшее место для хранения промежуточного значения - это Presenter.**